# How to avoid fragmented data during update operation when using TDengine?

Tags: fragment

I have imported a .csv dataset data into TDengine database with expired time tag and operated update function at specific property. Due to the random expired timestamp, fragmented data have been generated lead the query speed reduced. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid the generation of fragmented data or any re-organize fragmented data function?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").